# How to get around the FormSpree redirect?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I got my website over on the Github Pages Service. I'm trying to implement the FormSpree free contact form but after you submit the form, it redirects you to a different website. Something I'd like to avoid. So I looked it up on the internet and of course others wanted to get rid of it too (I omitted my email in the below picture).

[image]

This is the form I got above but it doesn't actually work at all. It worked before I tried to fiddle with it though.

Here is what the form looks like by default from FormSpree:

```
<form action="//formspree.io/your@email.com"
      method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="email" name="_replyto">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Here is my version (which worked fine before I tried to get around the redirect)

```
<div class=modal-body style="background-color: #454545">
    <p>Please use the form below to contact us regarding feedback or any questions you may have!
        We will never use the information given below to spam you and we will never pass on your
        information to a 3rd party.</p>
    <p>As we are using <a target="_blank" href="http://formspree.io">FormSpree</a> for this form
    please consult their privacy policy for any questions regarding this matter.</p>
    <form id="contactform" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Name</span>
                <input name="form-name-input" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Email</span>
                <input name="form-email-input" type="email" name="_replyto" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Subject</span>
                <input name="form-subject-input" type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Description</span>
                <textarea name="form-description-input" name="description" class="form-control" rows="4" cols="60" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="_gotcha" style="display:none" />
            <input class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" type="submit" id="form-submit-btn" value="Submit">
            <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="http://www.dynamicrealities.net" onclick="FormSentConfirmation()"/>
        </div>
        <script>
            var contactform =  document.getElementById('contactform');
            contactform.setAttribute('action', '//formspree.io/' + 'dynamicrealities@gmail.com');
        </script>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer" style="background-color: #333333">
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-bg" data-dismiss="modal" type="button" id="form-dismiss-btn" onclick="">Close</button>
</div>
```

And when I call `_next` I want it to execute the following alert:

```
function FormSentConfirmation() {
    alert('Thanks for the email, we\'ll be in touch promptly.');
}
```

When I press the Submit button, all that happens is that the form goes away but I don't receive any emails. I'm probably just doing this wrong as I am fairly new still to HTML/JavaScript.

Comment: I don't know FormSpree, but you should be able to check if the page gets redirected, then `return false;` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I have added the standard form they give you as example. As long as you put it in that structure and call `action="//formspree.io/your@email.com"
      method="POST"` on the form, FormSpree will do the rest.

Comment: Check www.enformed.io, works just as formspree but has a redirect out of the box

Comment: @Ivangrx not it is only available for gold and platinum plans...

Comment: As @eggrobot78 said, it's only available on paid plans now. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40831948/making-the-next-option-work-in-formspree#comment100149161_40831948 for more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow their AJAX example at the bottom: https://formspree.io/

```
$("#sendMessage").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "//formspree.io/dynamicrealities@gmail.com", 
        method: "POST",
        data: {message: "hello!"},
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

Remember to include jQuery as well for this to work. Remove the:

```
var contactform =  document.getElementById('contactform');
contactform.setAttribute('action', '//formspree.io/' + 'dynamicrealities@gmail.com
```

and replace it with my code and change the selector. Or use `$("form").on("submit"...`

Here is my example, which sends you a mail and prompts an alert for the user: http://jsfiddle.net/228d4snb/

Do anything you'd like to do right before that `return false;`

Comment: Oh okay. I totally missed that. I'll try it right now. Thanks!

Comment: @Vipar Trying to set up an example as we speak :P

Comment: So it works but, now it only sends "Hello!" to my mailbox :P Do I have to collect the value of each form element myself and then put it in an array to send? I imagine that would be the best solution.

Comment: @Vipar Yes that would be the best option to do. I included a `$.serialize()` example in mine, which basically sends all the form data as GET, so you can see what the message said. You should be able to put that into a better view! I'm glad I could help!

Comment: @Vipar You should add some IDs to those things you are looking for. `$('#contactform').find('subject')` is VERY bad. You should simply add IDs and select those instead.

Comment: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://formspree.io/dynamicrealities@gmail.com' from origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`,your jsfiddle can't perform the request.

Answer (score 11):

**Update:** The feature available only on paid plans.

Use this hidden input field inside the form for redirection after form submission. You can redirect users to a page that you like or you have created by using this code block.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_next" value="//site.io/thanks.html" />
```

replace **value** with a valid thank-you page URL.

Follow this link for a tutorial on [how to use Formspree](http://blog.webjeda.com/how-to-add-form-option-to-jekyll-websites) and also a [video demo](https://youtu.be/IP6HsgwQkvs)

Comment: Is there a way to use this with Reactjs?

Comment: It seems this feature is only for special plan https://help.formspree.io/hc/en-us/articles/360012378333--Thank-You-redirect

Comment: I made a different form solution called Web3Forms. It has the redirect feature by design. It's much easier for developers and has a generous free tier.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the form in an iframe so only the iframe gets redirected. What I did was create a separate html doc with just the contact form html (and any associated scripts) and then in my actual contact.html page I put:
`<iframe src="contact-form.html" class="container"></iframe>.`

Style the iframe to the appropriate size and with no border and it should work swimmingly.