# Making the _next option work in Formspree

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a contact form for a static website at [www.peek.solutions](http://www.peek.solutions). The contact form works, in that I'm (after confirmation of my e-mail address) able to receive e-mails at the given address. Here is the code used:

```
<form id="contactform" action="//formspree.io/kurt.peek@gmail.com" method="POST">
<div class="col-sm-7 slideanim">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="email" name="_replyto" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="5"></textarea><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="_next" value="//peek.solutions/confirmation.html" />
<input type="text" name="_gotcha" style="display:none" />   
</form>
```

The problem is that when I submit the form by pressing the "Submit" button, I'm redirected to Formspree's default confirmation page:

[image]

However, through the line

```
<input type="hidden" name="_next" value="//peek.solutions/confirmation.html" />
```

I was trying to make this confirmation page default to www.peek.solutions/confirmation.html. As far as I can tell, this line follows the documentation at https://formspree.io/. Can anyone tell why this is not working?

Comment: 2019 update: Available on: Gold, Platinum plans 
https://help.formspree.io/hc/en-us/articles/360012378333--Thank-You-redirect

Comment: @hubert17 Good call. I got burned by this as well. What's shitty about this is that they silently made our redirects not work without telling us or giving us an opportunity to change services or upgrade to a paid plan. Not cool.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter cofounder of Formspree here, we grandfathered in all forms that were using the _next option to ensure things should continue to work. if that's not the case, can you please reach out at https://help.formspree.io/hc/en-us/requests/new so we can investigate.

Comment: @rohit Thanks for the reply. It is indeed not the case. I'll create a new support request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating your URLs to include `http:` will fix the issue. so for the `_next` value it should be `http://peek.solutions/confirmation.html`,

To prevent exposing your email, and using the now legacy method of using your email in forms, you can sign up for a [free Formspree account](https://formspree.io/register) and generate a custom endpoint. More info on [legacy forms can be found here](https://help.formspree.io/hc/en-us/articles/360056076314-Phasing-out-legacy-forms-email-URLs).